# Python Turtle: Two ends of a 180 arc do not coincide?

Tags: python

I am trying an exercise which asks me to draw the letters of the alphabets using turtle in Python. So far I think I have a decent understanding of how to draw lines, curves, and shapes using forward/backward distance and turning angles.

I am trying to draw the letter 'B', and here is my design:

Figure 1:
[image: Figure 1]

Note that all the black lines are equal in distance, and the diameter of the arc is also equal to 1 black line. Here is the incomplete function I have:

```
def arc(t, r, angle, n):
    arc_length = 2*math.pi*r*(angle/360)
    def polyline(t, length, n):
        for i in range(n):
            t.fd(length/n)
            t.lt(angle/n)
    polyline(t, arc_length, n)

def draw_b(t):
    t.fd(30)
    arc(t, 30, 180, 10)
    t.fd(30)
    t.lt(90)
    t.fd(30)
    t.bk(60)
```

It should give me 2 exactly parallel lines connected by the bottom arc, but instead I get this:

Figure 2:
[image: Figure 2]

Ignoring the incomplete top part, **how can I fix this problem where the 2 ends of the arc clearly do not coincide, hence leaving a short "tail"? Have I done something wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `range(n+1)` to draw extra `fd()` at the end but then you will have to turn back `t.lt(-angle/n)`. Or keep `range(n)` and draw extra `fd()` without `lt()` after loop.

```
def polyline(t, length, n):
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length/n)
        t.lt(angle/n)
    t.fd(length/n)   # <--- extra `fd()` without `lt()`
```

---

```
import turtle
import math

def arc(t, r, angle, n):
    length = 2*math.pi*r*(angle/360)
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length/n)
        t.lt(angle/n)
    t.fd(length/n)

def draw_b(t):
    for _ in range(2):
        t.fd(30)
        arc(t, 30, 180, 10)
        t.fd(30)
        t.lt(90)
        t.fd(60)
        t.bk(60)
        t.lt(90)

draw_b(turtle.Turtle())
```

---

**EDIT:** in previons version I use `fd()` N+1 times, and `lf()` N times, but it looks better when there is `lf()` with `angle/2`, next `fd()` and `lf()` N times, and finally `lf()` with `-angle/2`. If you draw only `arc` with 3 segments then you will see it looks better.

```
import turtle
import math

def arc(t, r, angle, n):
    length = 2*math.pi*r*(angle/360)

    t.lt((angle/n)/2)

    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length/n)
        t.lt(angle/(n))

    t.lt((-angle/n)/2)

def draw_b(t):
    for _ in range(2):
        t.fd(30)
        arc(t, 30, 180, 10)
        t.fd(30)
        t.lt(90)
        t.fd(60)
        t.bk(60)
        t.lt(90)

t = turtle.Turtle()
arc(t, 30, 180, 3)
#draw_b(t)
```

---

for n=3

first version draws 4 segments

[image]

second version draws 3 segments

[image]

---

**BTW:** [gallery with other images created with turtle](https://blog.furas.pl/rysowanie-w-turtle-galeria-rysunkow.html).

Codes for image are on other pages but pages are not translated into English, yet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I need a bit of clarification on your very first line. What do you mean range(n) only gives n-1 elements, and how is it affecting the output? If I tried to draw a polyline with 3 segments and put n as 3, it seems to work fine.

Comment: it was wrong idea with `range()` - it gives `n` values and last value is `n-1` but it is not problem. Problem is that you need `lt` N times but `fd` N+1 times.

Comment: I added new version which draw better arc.

Comment: I understand now. The error was from the initial step of t.fd, but the endpoint never actually has a horizontal line as the turtle always keep turning after the initial t.fd, so we have to add t.fd at the end.

Comment: in first version i added missing horizontal line at the end. In new version I don't draw horizontal lines - and I think it looks better. When you want 3 segments then segments are in more expected positions.

Comment: I was just thinking of how to do that! Is there a reason you chose to do an initial turn of (angle/n)/2 ? why not just angle/n? 

Edit: I understand now, we need to turn (angle/n)/2 to get that orientation via simple geometry. Thanks!

Comment: I added images which show differences in both versions.

Comment: I use angel/2 because I don't want horizontal lines - I can always add it manually, and if I add 30px then it will look like 30px and not 30+horizontal_line_from_arc. If I rotate  angle/2 then I have 2 simetrical arc - I draw one of them but if I will draw second one then it will be identical/simetrical.

Comment: BTW: I have gallery with figures created with turtle: [gallery-turtle](https://blog.furas.pl/rysowanie-w-turtle-galeria-rysunkow.html). Codes are on other pages but pages are not translated to English.